# convert an image from sRGB to indexed. Color palette is ~400 colors, final image to use a max of 70 colors

Tags: linux, scripting, imagemagick, gimp

**What I want to do:**

I would like to change an image to indexed, provide the color map, and set the max number of colors in the image to 70 of the provided 400. I would like this final image to be exported in some kind of text based format.

**What  I have so far:**

I have the color palette as a text list of ~400 HEX values and their RGB equivalents in an excel spreadsheet. I can create a csv or tab-separated file of whatever of the two formats are needed (hex or RGB).Using imagemagik, the `-remap` argument will do the palette conversion, and the `-color` argument to limit the number of colors to 70. If the indexed image is saved as bmp, I can easily import a BMP into c++/python/matlab/octave and do some operations on the array and write that to text file.

**Where I'm stuck:**

I'm struggling to efficiently get my text-based list of ascii values into a nice colormap image that I can feed to the `-remap` argument. I know I could manually create one by painstakingly creating an image and making one pixel each color in the colormap, but there must be a better way!

**Other Stuff:**

If you have any other advice about the process I've mentioned above or any suggestions as to how I can do this better/faster/more efficiently, I'm all ears!